# Flying mosquito problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, relative-motion

Let's say there is a car and its doors and windows are closed. Basically it is a closed space inside. There is a mosquito hovering right in the center of closed space of the car. While doing so the mosquito is not in physical contact of the car.  Now, a driver starts the car and accelerates quickly. Question is, would the mosquito smash into the rear glass or would it continie to hover at the center of the car?

Comment: My experience is that the mosquito will end up hovering somewhere behind my ear, yet I'm never able to swat it...

Comment: Question is, would the mosquito **want** to smash into the rear glass ? (I.e. it's not about Physics, but rather about mosquito intentions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A fly in an accelerating car](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53475/)

Comment: You can always try an experiment with soap bubbles in the car. Kids love it!

Answer (score 3):

**General idea:** The air in the car accelerates with it. Air is [compressible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility), so, during acceleration, it's denser on the rear than on the front (similarly, in a rotating cylinder, there is a radial density gradient, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127565/226902)).
Assume constant acceleration: this is indistinguishable from a "horizontal" gravitational field (see the [Equivalence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle)) that creates a [stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Stratification) in density, analogous to what happens in our atmosphere, as given by [hydrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troposphere#Pressure).
**The mosquito** (or, for simplicity a "dust particle"), **will move because the air must find a new hydrostatic equilibrium that is not just uniform density.** Since air must change its density configuration, this gives rise to a transient current because of the [continuity equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172813/226902). The dust particle will be [advected](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396971/226902) by such a current.
*This effect is **too small to be observed** in a car but gets proportionally bigger by increasing the **acceleration** and/or the **length** of the vehicle.* Details on the "accelerating" equilibrium (i.e. equilibrium in a gravitational field) are discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291621/226902).

**Rough estimate of the effect:** Assume, for mere convenience, that your vehicle acceleration is $g\approx 9.8 m/s$. We know that (approximatively) air density changes by 10% in 1 km of elevation, see the [Pressure-Elevation graph](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-altitude-pressure-d_462.html). Assuming [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) for air (and constant temperature everywhere), the same is true also for the density (i.e. density is proportional to the pressure).

Therefore: if your vehicle is undergoing **constant** $1g$ acceleration and is long $1km$, the air in the front is 10% less dense than air in the rear. This assumes [hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium), which is reached after an initial *transient* is damped (air is a bit viscous). The fine details of this transient depend on the exact dynamics: you have to solve the hydrodynamic equations for a gas in an accelerating box, for a given prescribed acceleration and shape of the box. Therefore, the transient phase depends on the [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)), namely on how you go from zero acceleration to constant finite acceleration and finally reach a new hydrostatic equilibrium.

Of course, your car is not 1km long and can not accelerate at $g$. However, you can **rescale the result**.
For example, let's say [it's a bus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94210/226902) and it's 10m (again, let's keel the unrealistic acceleration of $g$).
Hence, from the front to the rear density changes by $10\% \times 10m/1km = 10\%/100=0.1\%$: nearly 1 out of 1000 "air particles" that were on the front now it's on the rear (very roughly). There is a net air displacement from the initial equilibrium (uniform air density) to the "accelerating" equilibrium. Assuming that your mosquito is not a mosquito but a "[dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust) particle", we can conclude that it has been displaced accordingly. This displacement is not noticeable because the dust particle will undergo random [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion). However, the **nature of such tiny displacement is not stochastic** (like Brownian motion) **but systematic**, due to the fact that **acceleration modifies the hydrostatic solution of the air in the car, which is not just uniform density**. Now, by changing the acceleration to a more reasonable one, the result scales proportionally and becomes even smaller.